# Текст из div отправить на стену Вконтакте

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть текст, которая находится в div, есть кнопка "Предложить новость".  При нажатие на кнопку, текст публикуется на стене ВКонтакте. Каким образом вытащить текст из div? Смог сделать пост ВК только из input и textarea (так как они являются элементами формы). Скрипт работает на PHP.

Comment: с помощью js, например. А смысл хранить тект для публикации в div? Нужно же иметь возможность вводить текст. Для этого есть элементы формы. Их значения и отправляются. Так что или так. Или так.

Comment: Да, есть input, куда пишем данные. Есть div, где показывает как будут отображаться эти данные. Мне надо полностью все данные в диве отправить на стену

Comment: Так в чём ваш вопрос? Как получить данные из div? Или что?

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById('div-with-text');
var textFromDiv = element.textContent || element.innerText;
```